# Which is better: a rotor / prop followed by a stator, or contra rotating rotors / props?

Tags: propeller, engine, propulsion, thrust

It is all in the title.

I'm interested in power absorbed/used for a given thrust, or thrust generated for a given power (same diameters of course).

Just thrust and power.  Ignore materials, electric vs turbine, complexity of the  contra-rotating mechanism, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Undisturbed inlet flow provides the highest efficiency.

- The single rotor with stator has a straightforward inflow; outflow will have a tangential component which is lost for thrust generation. The stator will bend the outflow back in the axial direction, but there still remain pressure increases with blade passing frequency.
- The contra rotating rotor has one of the rotors in the disturbed flow of the first rotor - this second rotor will therefore have lower efficiency in transforming engine power into thrust.